# she was so angry she could

Tags: word-request

I am writing a story and a girl screamed at somebody and to help the people reading I want to tell them how mad she was, but I can't think of anything, the sentence is:

> **She was so angry she could...**

I thought maybe I should try:

> She was so angry she could **punch a locker**

since she is in a school, or

> She was so angry she could **not speak**

but that would not make sense she screamed at someone.

Comment: This is unclear to me, can you explain some more? Hint: proper layout helps. Your paragraph is one big sentence.

Comment: In addition to the “proper layout helps” comment, so does proper English (especially here on ELL!). It’s not `i can’t, i wanna`, it’s `I can’t, I want to`. I’ve tidied up this question, but please be more careful with your next one. You can visit our [Contributor’s Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) for a wealth of helpful tips.

Answer (score 2):

To tell the people how mad she is you could write:

> She was so angry that her mind went blank.

Comment: I was going with a exegesis so that he could think more.

Comment: @Ambasharkar - The problem is, “She gone blank” is neither idiomatic nor grammatical. Your answer had to either be fixed or deleted.